# python: functions *sometimes* maintain a reference to their module

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, execfile, refcounting

If I execfile a module, and remove all (of my) reference to that module, it's functions continue to work as expected. That's normal.

However, if that execfile'd module imports other modules, and I remove all references to *those* modules, the functions defined in those modules start to see all their global values as None. This causes things to fail spectacularly, of course, and in a very supprising manner (TypeError NoneType on string constants, for example).

I'm surprised that the interpreter makes a special case here; `execfile` doesn't seem special enough to cause functions to behave differently wrt module references.

My question: Is there any clean way to make the execfile-function behavior recursive (or global for a limited context) with respect to modules imported by an execfile'd module?

---

To the curious:

The application is reliable configuration reloading under buildbot. The buildbot configuration is executable python, for better or for worse. If the executable configuration is a single file, things work fairly well. If that configuration is split into modules, any imports from the top-level file get stuck to the original version, due to the semantics of `__import__` and `sys.modules`. My strategy is to hold the contents of sys.modules constant before and after configuration, so that each reconfig looks like an *initial* configuration. This *almost* works except for the above function-global reference issue.

---

Here's a repeatable demo of the issue:

```
import gc
import sys
from textwrap import dedent


class DisableModuleCache(object):
    """Defines a context in which the contents of sys.modules is held constant.
    i.e. Any new entries in the module cache (sys.modules) are cleared when exiting this context.
    """
    modules_before = None
    def __enter__(self):
        self.modules_before = sys.modules.keys()
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        for module in sys.modules.keys():
            if module not in self.modules_before:
                del sys.modules[module]
        gc.collect()  # force collection after removing refs, for demo purposes.


def reload_config(filename):
    """Reload configuration from a file"""
    with DisableModuleCache():
        namespace = {}
        exec open(filename) in namespace
        config = namespace['config']
        del namespace

    config()


def main():
    open('config_module.py', 'w').write(dedent('''
    GLOBAL = 'GLOBAL'
    def config():
        print 'config! (old implementation)'
        print GLOBAL
    '''))

    # if I exec that file itself, its functions maintain a reference to its modules,
    # keeping GLOBAL's refcount above zero
    reload_config('config_module.py')
    ## output:
    #config! (old implementation)
    #GLOBAL

    # If that file is once-removed from the exec, the functions no longer maintain a reference to their module.
    # The GLOBAL's refcount goes to zero, and we get a None value (feels like weakref behavior?).
    open('main.py', 'w').write(dedent('''
    from config_module import *
    '''))

    reload_config('main.py')
    ## output:
    #config! (old implementation)
    #None

    ## *desired* output:
    #config! (old implementation)
    #GLOBAL

    acceptance_test()


def acceptance_test():
    # Have to wait at least one second between edits (on ext3),
    # or else we import the old version from the .pyc file.
    from time import sleep
    sleep(1)

    open('config_module.py', 'w').write(dedent('''
    GLOBAL2 = 'GLOBAL2'
    def config():
        print 'config2! (new implementation)'
        print GLOBAL2

        ## There should be no such thing as GLOBAL. Naive reload() gets this wrong.
        try:
            print GLOBAL
        except NameError:
            print 'got the expected NameError :)'
        else:
            raise AssertionError('expected a NameError!')
    '''))

    reload_config('main.py')
    ## output:
    #config2! (new implementation)
    #None
    #got the expected NameError :)

    ## *desired* output:
    #config2! (new implementation)
    #GLOBAL2
    #got the expected NameError :)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide a minimal working example.

Comment: If you don't provide explicit globals or locals, `execfile` executes the file in the current globals and locals. It doesn't do anything like a module import or create a new namespace; it's pretty near equivalent to `exec open(filename).read()`

Comment: @Marcin, user2357112: I've added a reproducible demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider `import`ing the configuration instead of `exec`ing it.

I use `import` for a similar purpose, and it works great. (specifically, `importlib.import_module(mod)`).  Though, my configs consists mainly of primitives, not real functions.

Like you, I also have a "guard" context to restore the original contents of `sys.modules` after the import. Plus, I use `sys.dont_write_bytecode = True` (of course, you can add that to your `DisableModuleCache` -- set to True in `__enter__` and to False in `__exit__`). This would ensure the config actually "runs" each time you import it.

The main difference between the two approaches, (other than the fact you don't have to rely on the state the interpreter stays in after `exec`ing (which I consider semi-unclean)), is that the config files are identified by their *module-name/path* (as used for importing) rather than the *file name*.

---

**EDIT: A [link to the implementation](https://figura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/figura/importutils.html) of this approach, as part of the [Figura](https://figura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package.**

Comment: Indeed, import_module has the behavior that I want; gc'd modules don't have their attributes all set to None. It seems to me though that this is a behavior of module objects rather than anything else, and I'm using the same definition of module objects in both cases, so I can't entirely see what the relevant difference is. Additionally, I'm stuck on python2.6 :(

Comment: Update: I see that python2.7 has a backport of importlib. It has the same bad None'ing behavior as in the OP. Also, I  note that `__import__` has the same behavior as importlib.import_module in both versions; this global-dropping behavior seems to be one of the myriad things fixed in python3.

Comment: Finally: the exec() strategy in the OP works just fine in python3 =/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need the 'acceptance_test' part of things here.  The issue isn't actually weakrefs, it's modules' behavior on destruction.  They clear out their `__dict__` on delete.  I vaguely remember that this is done to break ref cycles.  I suspect that global references in function closures do something fancy to avoid a hash lookup on every invocation, which is why you get `None` and not a `NameError`.

Here's a much shorter sscce:

```
import gc
import sys
import contextlib
from textwrap import dedent


@contextlib.contextmanager
def held_modules():
    modules_before = sys.modules.keys()
    yield
    for module in sys.modules.keys():
        if module not in modules_before:
            del sys.modules[module]
    gc.collect()  # force collection after removing refs, for demo purposes.

def main():
    open('config_module.py', 'w').write(dedent('''
    GLOBAL = 'GLOBAL'
    def config():
        print 'config! (old implementation)'
        print GLOBAL
    '''))
    open('main.py', 'w').write(dedent('''
    from config_module import *
    '''))

    with held_modules():
        namespace = {}
        exec open('main.py') in namespace
        config = namespace['config']
    config()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Or, to put it another way, don't delete modules and expect their contents to continue functioning.

Comment: That all makes sense, but you've neglected the fact that the behavior is different (and more desirable) when modules are executed directly. I posit that it's because directly-exec'd modules fall out of scope before their functions often enough that someone cared about it working correctly. Do you have any clue where in cpython I would find the divergence between the two cases?

Comment: I left the 'acceptance test' there in case someone thought they had a better reload_config implementation. ;)

Comment: I've found that simply running `gc.get_referrers(module)` just before deleting the module has the side-effect of adding the necessary references to make everything work correctly. Bizarre. This makes things work perfectly in all python versions 2.5+. Again I find that exec works quite differently than import; `__import__` continues to have the same bad behavior in 2.5-2.7.